# vectors of pointers adding and accessing

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

The problem is that i don't get the expected output here. I have a class for Node which has the vector of pointers called neigbours. I want to put in the object neigbour into the vector.

```
Node current = Node(1, 1, street , 2, 2);
Node neighbour = Node(2, 2);
neighbour.instreets.push_back(Street(1, 1, street, 2, 2));
nodes.push_back(neighbour);

current.neighours.push_back(&nodes.at(0));
nodes.push_back(current);
```

then i want to access it to print out.

```
cout << nodes[1].x << " " << nodes[1].y << endl;
cout << "- " << nodes[0].outstreets[0].name << endl;
cout << "ends " << nodes[1].neighours.at(0)->x << " " << nodes[1].neighours[0]->y << endl;
```

But i get some random numbers instead for the neighbour coordinades. Am i accessing them in a wrong way?

expected output is

```
1 1
- street
ends 2 2
```

EDIT:
nodes is a vector of Node objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you add an element to `nodes` vector, its memory can be reallocated. This means that its elements are moved to a different place in memory, and pointers to them are invalidated.

In particular, the address you have taken with `&nodes.at(0)` is not valid anymore after executing `nodes.push_back(current);`

There are multiple ways to fix it, but the simplest one is to make `nodes` a `deque` instead of `vector`. Deque does not reallocate memory, so your code will work fine.

Comment: So i am not adding the neighbour to the vector correctly?

Comment: The problem is that you are taking a pointer to the memory owned by vector `nodes`.  See edited answer for how to fix it.